# Where can I see the created package in Azure DevOps to upload to the store?

Tags: azure-devops, windows-store

I want to create packages to load to the store.

Here is the YAML so far

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  appxPackageDir: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config

    nugetConfigPath: 'MyApp.Win10/mynuget.config'


- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    platform: 'x64'
    solution:  '**\*.sln'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload'
```

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps) mention the Artifacts explorer on the Artifacts tab of the builds results page.  But I cant find it.

I have also looked at the Artifacts in the project but they only contain some nuget packages I put there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the artifacts becuase you don't have the ["Publish Build Artifacts" task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts).

For example, add this task:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
     pathtoPublish: '$(appxPackageDir)' 
     artifactName: 'drop'
```